# What does a splat operator do when it has no variable name?

Tags: ruby

I was browsing through the `Camping` codebase when I saw a constructor with a splat being used like this:

```
class Fruit 
  def initialize(*)
  end
end
```

I tried looking up "splat with no variable name" on this site and Google, but I couldn't find anything besides info about splat being used with a variable name like this `*some_var`, but not without it. I tried playing around with this on a repl, and I tried stuff like:

```
class Fruit 
  def initialize(*)
      puts *
  end
end

Fruit.new('boo')
```

but that runs into this error:

```
(eval):363: (eval):363: compile error (SyntaxError)
(eval):360: syntax error, unexpected kEND
(eval):363: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
```

If this question hasn't been asked already, can someone explain what this syntax does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically a splat like this is used to specify arguments that are not used by the method but that are used by the corresponding method in a superclass. Here's an example:

```
class Child < Parent
  def do_something(*)
    # Do something
    super
  end
end
```

This says, call this method in the super class, passing it all the parameters that were given to the original method.

source: Programming ruby 1.9 (Dave Thomas)

Comment: This is just a special case of what Josnidhin mentions.

Answer (score 4):

It behaves similar to *args but you cant refer to then in method body

```
def print_test(a, *)
  puts "#{a}"
end

print_test(1, 2, 3, 'test')
```

This will print 1.